# Are there any good strategies for the SC2 Mod "Footmen"?

Tags: starcraft-2, mods

I've been playing the Footmen mod for SC2 a lot lately and i really enjoy it. I was wondering if anyone has some good strategies for this mod? What hero should i choose and what stats should i upgrade first? Is it better to stick with the lower tier units and upgrade armor/weapons or do it the other way (first level up units, then armor/weapons)? Any other suggestions on how to win?

Comment: I haven't seen it yet. Is it anything like the War 3 footment frenzy?

Comment: @Jonn, it is similar

Comment: Dang. I've been looking and it seems we don't have that on the SEA server. I've been waiting for a footies in SC2 for a while now.

Comment: This one surely needs more attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its only published in Europe
Theres a lot strategies i think. Theres a forum (http://footmen.de.gg/), maybe check this out, strategies and other stuff is discussed there.

From what ive seen, building reapers (terran tier 1) and then doing attack and armor upgrades is a pretty good strategy. Or buying a grenady launcher + armor + other items for your hero is also good.